# System Hangs and mouse keep loading

Tags: 18.04, gnome, hard-drive

It started recently and I think my Hard drive maybe failing.
When I boot my system and enter password, it comes on okay, then after maybe a minute or so, it brings up the Help(Ubuntu Desktop Guide) and my mouse starts loading.
Immediately, the system starts lagging or hangs.

The only thing I might be able to do is shut down.

It's happening also to my new Hard Drive too.

Please any info on this?

New drive:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Old drive:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Memtest:
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application SMART Data window for BOTH disks (make sure to show scrolled text).

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Are these HDD or SSD? Internal SATA, and/or external USB? Old disk vs new disk? Laptop or desktop? Please describe.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema okay. There are HHD, internal in my laptop. Old and new HDD.

Comment: Old laptop, or newer laptop? Did you add the 2nd internal drive (maybe replacing a DVD drive?)? What brand of drives? 5400 or 7200 rpm? Separate SATA drive cables? Both drives are erroring, and I suspect a temperature problem. Maybe even a power supply problem. Do you hear cooling fans running?

Comment: An old laptop, HP 635, I just got a new drive. Both of them having or behaving the same and sometimes on boot, it shows details of PC and then the beep sound. I think it's 5400, my fan was bad, repaired it. Hear it running tho @heynnema

Comment: Sounds like I was correct. Heating problem due to bad fan. Have the SMART Data windows for either drive continue to show errors?

Comment: I'll put together a quick answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful, by clicking on the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, still that `Airflow Temperature` error. Thinking of buying external fan too. I'll try your answer when I get to the office this week.

Comment: As I suggest in my answer, monitor the SMART Data, and in the case of "Airflow Termperature" just assure that the actual event count doesn't increase, otherwise you still have a problem. Hopefully you're not cooking your disks and your motherboard. Adding the 2nd internal drive changed the ambient internal temperature for the entire laptop, and also changed the airflow characteristics. After bad blocking the disks, please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: status please...

Comment: I don't understand the monitor aspect, do I have control over that?

Comment: By "monitor" I mean to "occasionally observe/review" the `SMART Data` to insure that the "Airflow Temperature" counts don't increase, indicating that you still have a problem. Have you bad blocked your HDD's yet?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

Two different HDD's showing similar read and ECC errors. Suspect a heat problem.

Sure enough, the cooling fan was bad. Replaced.

Occasionally observe/review the `SMART Data` for looking for additional/new read and ECC errors.

---

You should do good backups, and then bad block both disks, using this procedure...

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure
```

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Yeah good day. I just tried this now and as I started the `bad block` it did the same thing. It hang after bringing up the Ubuntu Desktop Guide.

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE And you were booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Explain exactly what you did.

Comment: I boot to live USB (Try Ubuntu) without installing it. It still hanged.

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: you said 4 test?

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE yes, there are 4 tests, make sure that all 4 complete without errors.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the image of the test. Maybe I did it wrongly. You're suggesting that it could be RAM? I don't know right now. @heynnema

Comment: You did it correctly. The only concern that I have is that you have two different speed RAM sticks installed. The system looks like it has a 1333 speed, but RAM slot 0 has a 2G RAM stick that's 1600... now RAM sticks **should** step down to 1333, but who knows if yours does. It might be instructive to temporarily remove the 2G RAM stick and see if things improve.

Comment: I took out the 2G RAM, it work to an extent before having the issue again

Comment: Thank you for trying that. Did you ever bad block your disks? I'm concerned that either you have two disks failing in a similar fashion, or you've got something else like a power adapter not putting out enough power for two drives, or a motherboard, that's fried to due the fan issue. You might try another power adapter, or temporarily disconnecting the 2nd drive, and see if things improve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's motherboard. For the drives, I use them one at a time. The disk check suggest they're fine. Maybe I need a new PC

Comment: @connelblaze I'd temporarily remove the 2nd drive and see if the 1st drive behaves itself (as seen by the SMART error counts).

Comment: Okay. I did that. Still the same issue. It tries to work for awhile before doing that. I'm just tired of the PC. Now I have to look for another